# Change Background Image Multiple Times JS (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

```
 var images = [
  'http://www.pl/realizacje/wordpressx2/wp-content/themes/nex/images/livestream.jpg',
 'http://www.pl/realizacje/wordpressx2/wp-content/themes/nex/images/livestream1.jpg',
 'http://www.pl/realizacje/wordpressx2/wp-content/themes/nex/images/livestream3.jpg',
 'http://www.pl/realizacje/wordpressx2/wp-content/themes/nex/images/livestream4.jpg'
],
    i = 0,
    n = images.length;

$("#change-image").click(function(){ 
   $("#livestream").css({backgroundImage: "url("+ images[i++ % n] +")" });
});



<div id="zmianatapety"><button id="change-image">ZMIEŃ TŁO</button></div> </div>
```

To change image background, in html version it works perfect, but now i prepare theme for wordpress, and as you know style.css is in the theme folder, and the problem is that the script does not see style.css and not work.

if I can somehow add to the script address of style.css?

Comment: enqueue the js file in functions.php and it should work

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/and and https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Comment: Also another solution: you don't need Javascript to do that. You can do that all in CSS, which would save you having to register your Javascript.

Comment: Aeolingamenfel how to do that? :)

Comment: j08691,  Dhaval Chheda,   it works! thanks :)